# Long garbage collection times dropping network connections but not bouncing the pod in Kubernetes

Tags: java, kubernetes, garbage-collection

I have the following scenario:

1. I have a pod running an application with two sidecar containers.
2. All three containers have multiple network connections (around 7 servers are connected to them). They are constantly downloading/sending files or keeping a connection to get data from other servers, including stock exchange servers.
3. The Kubernetes version is v1.24.7+rke2r1
4. The Java version is openjdk_zulu8 (8.0.392-0) - jre1.8.0_362-amd64
5. The images were built using docker 1.13.1
6. The Linux image is RHEL 7.9 (Maipo)
7. We're not using any cloud service, this is our internal K8s environment.
8. We're using Ceph as storage
9. The heap memory limits are not specified, we let the JVM decide.
10. Our Prometheus/Grafana graphs are showing no issues with resources, so we don't believe that it's a resources issue, but this is how we're setting up memory and CPU:

- Main container:

  ```
  limits:
    cpu: 3000m
    memory: 10Gi
  requests:
    cpu: 3000m
    memory: 10Gi
  ```
- Sidecar container 1:

  ```
  limits:
    cpu: 3000m
    memory: 4400Mi
  requests:
    cpu: 2000m
    memory: 4000Mi
  ```
- Sidecar container 2:

  ```
  limits:
    cpu: 3000m
    memory: 4400Mi
  requests:
    cpu: 2000m
    memory: 4000Mi
  ```

The problem that I'm facing is that all of the sudden our applications are freezing for garbage collection for several minutes and stopping all the threads. This has happened on all three containers. This ends up dropping all the network connections since these applications must be heartbeating to keep the connections alive. The weird thing is that this doesn't really stop the application, so the pod is not restarted.

We've tried to tweak the java parameters to show more data regarding the GC (and add more resources), but we really can't find the issue here (that's why you see all these fancy extra parameters, that we've added after seeing the issue). Any help/hint is very welcomed.

Main java call parameters:

```
/usr/java/jre1.8.0_362-amd64/bin/java -showversion -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XshowSettings:system -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=604800000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=604800000 -XX:+SafepointTimeout -XX:SafepointTimeoutDelay=500 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseContainerSupport -XX:ActiveProcessorCount=2 -XX:+PrintSafepointStatistics -XX:PrintSafepointStatisticsCount=1 -javaagent:/opt/jhiccup/lib/jhiccup-2.0.10.jar=-d,5000,-i,1000,-s,3,-l
```

When there's the GC issue, we start seeing CPU throttling and the Sync column going higher:

```
49335.605: RevokeBias                       [      77          0              0    ]      [     0     0     0     0     0    ]  0
         vmop                    [threads: total initially_running wait_to_block]    [time: spin block sync cleanup vmop] page_trap_count
49335.605: RevokeBias                       [      77          0              0    ]      [     0     0     0     0     0    ]  0
         vmop                    [threads: total initially_running wait_to_block]    [time: spin block sync cleanup vmop] page_trap_count
49340.629: RevokeBias                       [      76          0              0    ]      [     0     0 21728     0     0    ]  0
```

I was looking at the TOP command and saw a lot of processes in this Status = D, that is uninterruptible sleep. Looks like something in the CEPH is freezing the whole application. Did someone see this before?

[image: Status D print]

This is the print of the GC statistics right after the freezing happening. Note that the sync column has a very high value:

[image: High Sync values in GC]

Comment: You are not providing any details related to memory configurations, usage or those GC details that you configured to be displayed. And why are you using those specific GC related configurations? What was the decision process to select those configurations?

Comment: Do you have a gc log?

Comment: We've added PrintGCDetails and other things to get more verbosity.

Comment: `-XX:ActiveProcessorCount=2` you may want to set that higher, though not sure if that will solve your problem. In any case, it sounds like your application may need more heap than that 4 GiB you're currently allowing it.

Comment: Thank you Mark, will try that and post here the results.

Comment: I've fixed the heap issues removing the Xmx and Xms parameters. Increasing the ActiveProcessorCount didn't fix the issue, unfortunately...

Comment: I have the impression that there's some bug on Kubernetes or the Docker that we're using, because another team in our company is seeing the same issue and their environment is totally separated from ours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```bash
+---------------------+
| Kubernetes Cluster  |
|   ┌───────────────┐ |
|   |    Pod        | |
|   | ┌───────────┐ | |
|   | | Container | | |
|   | |  Main App | | | <---- Java Application
|   | └───────────┘ | |
|   | ┌───────────┐ | |
|   | | Sidecar 1 | | | <---- Sidecar Container
|   | └───────────┘ | |
|   | ┌───────────┐ | |
|   | | Sidecar 2 | | | <---- Sidecar Container
|   | └───────────┘ | |
|   └───────────────┘ |
|                     |
+---------------------+
```

Since you are using G1GC, make sure it is properly configured. Given your current settings (`-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200`), the JVM aims for short GC pauses, but the heap might be too large or fragmented. Consider tuning the heap size and the G1GC specific flags: see "[Garbage First Garbage Collector Tuning](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/g1gc.html)" from [Monica Beckwith](https://github.com/mo-beck).

For instance, using the [latest version of Java 8](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/release_changes.html) (to benefit from any fix/optimization)

```bash
/usr/java/jre1.8.0_391-amd64/bin/java -showversion -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XshowSettings:system \
-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -XX:+PrintGCDetails \
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -Xmx8G -Xms4G \  # Adjusted Heap Size
-Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=604800000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=604800000 \
-XX:+SafepointTimeout -XX:SafepointTimeoutDelay=500 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true \
-XX:+UseContainerSupport -XX:ActiveProcessorCount=2 -XX:+PrintSafepointStatistics \
-XX:PrintSafepointStatisticsCount=1 -javaagent:/opt/jhiccup/lib/jhiccup-2.0.10.jar=-d,5000,-i,1000,-s,3,-l
```

Use tools like [`jstat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jstat.html), [`jmap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr014.html), or [Java Mission Control](https://blogs.oracle.com/java/post/java-mission-control-now-serving-openjdk-binaries-too) to get a deeper insight into the JVM's behavior, especially focusing on heap usage and GC logs.

Double-check your Kubernetes resource limits and requests. Overcommitting CPU or memory can lead to throttling and performance issues. Also, make sure your limits are not too high, which might lead to inefficient GC: see "[Kubernetes CPU Limits and Throttling](https://komodor.com/learn/kubernetes-cpu-limits-throttling/)" from [Itiel Shwartz](https://twitter.com/itielshwartz) for illustration.

Also investigate how your application interacts with [Ceph storage](https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/storage/ceph). Long GC times could be symptomatic of I/O waits. Use tools like [`iotop`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/iotop) to monitor disk I/O.

---

The [OP Arthur Accioly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179589/arthur-accioly) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77649180/long-garbage-collection-times-dropping-network-connections-but-not-bouncing-the/77676128#comment137086539_77676128):

> The issue was fixed changing the CEPH filesystem to Ceph RBD.
>
> The filesystem was taking too long to process the Java requests and was causing this weird issue that nobody documented before afaik.
> The problem is that Ceph RBD cannot be shared between multiple PODs, so we've had to adjust our architecture to work around that.

So switching to Ceph RBD resolved the garbage collection and network drop issues, but introduced a new challenge due to RBD's limitation of not being shareable between multiple pods.

A possible workaround would be to adjust your pod structure to work with individual RBD volumes. That might mean having dedicated volumes for each pod or reorganizing how data is accessed and stored.

If data sharing between pods is essential, consider using other methods like object storage ([Ceph S3](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/radosgw/s3/)), databases, or implementing a service layer for data access.

For applications that require persistent storage, [StatefulSets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) can be a better choice than Deployments. They offer unique volume per pod, which aligns well with the one-volume-per-pod constraint of Ceph RBD.

To manage data consistency and sharing, leverage RBD's [cloning](https://docs.ceph.com/en/quincy/cephfs/fs-volumes/?highlight=cloning#cloning-snapshots) or [snapshotting](https://docs.ceph.com/en/quincy/rbd/rbd-snapshot/) features. That allows for creating read-only snapshots for other pods or cloning volumes for new pods without extensive data transfer.

Comment: Hi VonC, thank you so much for your answer. I strongly believe that the issue is in the Ceph Storage as you've mentioned in the end. I'm reviewing everything that you've said and will escalate to our team responsible for our K8s infrastructure.

Comment: @ArthurAccioly Good call. I am interested in your team's feedback.

Comment: The issue was fixed changing the CEPH filesystem to Ceph RBD. The filesystem was taking too long to process the Java requests and was causing this weird issue that nobody documented before afaik. The problem is that Ceph RBD cannot be shared between multiple PODs, so we've had to adjust our architecture to workaround that.

Comment: @ArthurAccioly Thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, as well as suggested a few workarounds.